# Questions about the Boundary Value Check

Tags: junit, boundary

I'm doing my JUnit homework and need some explanations here.

Here's the quotation from my homework description:

One of the issues with boundary conditions is that the system needs to behave well even if the boundary is approached multiple times. This should be obvious, but it doesn't always happen in practice.

*Remember that we can characterize an object as state and behavior. Typically, the state is not directly accessible, but instead, is accessed indirectly by means of the behavior. That is, the behavior reflects the state of the object.*

*Now, if we think about boundaries in math, it might not be too surprising to imagine the the value at some boundary will be different if we approach that boundary in different ways. So, if the value can be likened to the state, the state at the boundary may vary depending on how we got there. This would mean that the behavior could be different.*

***To make objects that behave consistently, we would have to insure that the internal state at those boundaries is consistent. So, test cases should check this assumption. To receive challenge points for this homework assignment enhance your test cases so that potential problems around the boundaries may be discovered.***

*Clearly mark the Challenge test cases with the string "### challenge ###" in the comments. Include in those comments what boundary is being tested, and how you're guessing that the state of the object may be different depending on how the boundary is being approached.*

I don't understand this especially the highlighted part. What does he mean by "object behave consistently" and the "potential probelms"?

Also, how is this different than general boundary check that will just throws the exception and i expected in the JUnit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the details of the homework, an answer could only be somewhat generic, but I'll try.

Boundary checking is not just exception checking, its about seeing which paths in your code are execution on what condition. If you have control statements, loops, if-else, switch, etc you have to verify, on what conditions (of your internal state) those statements are processed in what way.

To me, boundary testing is that you change certain values of an instance field in a way that would cause the behavior to run through different branches of your code.

for example, you have this behavior:

```
if(someInstanceValue > 5) {
    return "great";
} else {
    return "poor";
}
```

Now you could test with data for `someInstanceValue` that define the boundary

- 4 : "poor"
- 5 : "great"

If you have multiple fields in your class, *all* of them define the state but only some of them may affect a certain path in your code. As the test is a specification of your class under test, written in code, you should specify which fields are relevant to a function, and which are not (by leaving them out).
So you should set up your instance-under-test accordingly (calling all setters) or if you require more complex objects, you could use frameworks like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) to specify the state (in a `when().thenReturn()` syntax).

If you want to verify if you covered all your boundaries, you could run a mutation test against your suite using a mutation testing tool like [PIT](http://pitest.org/). It will flip the switches in your code (i.e. replacing a `<` with a `>=`) to check whether your test will fail. Often, it's a good source of inspiration for improving the way you test.

Neverthelss, some parts of the homework assignment sound a bit confusing to me. You may approach a boundary from two sides, ok, but there is no such thing as a state that represents *THE* boundary, you're either on one or the other side of the boundary. If the way, how you approached one side of a boundary matters, and the object behaves differently depending on that "history" of how you reached that state, the history becomes part of the state. In other words: different history = different state.

Keep in mind: every instance field is part of the state. Every possible *combination* of values of your instance fields defines a single state. Every transition from one combination to another is a state transition triggered by calling a behavior. No think of your test describing this statemachine, be listing the triple of `{currentState,input} -> nextState` (with input being method invocation). Wich is basically the [Given-When-Then](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/GivenWhenThen.html) structure good tests should have.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just have one more question : in the quotation what does it mean by "make objects that behave consisently " ?

Comment: That's the part I find confusing too, because object typically do not change their behavior at runtime as this would mean to alter the bytecode (behavior = methods), and because method implementation are not changed at runtime. The only thing that can affect the result of calling a behavior is the current state (the sum of all its field values). So in your test you have to ensure, that all fields that are relevant to the method you want to test, are set accordingly. In case you rely on default values, you should make separate tests for default values and custom values.

Comment: On 2nd thougt, maybe it's an overloading of the concept "behavior". Objects have state (the fields) and behavior (methods). In natural language the behavior is what's observable and is a combination of state AND "activity". For example, the outcome of a certain activity may depend on your internal state, i.e. stress level, sleep, hunger, etc. How you act, is whats we tyically call 'behavior'. Back to your tests and objects, the may act differently (same method called twice) if the internal state is different. And that's what you specify in your test Given StateA; When methodB; Then outcomeC.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense, thanks for the help again!

Comment: So we are actually just working on a simple bounded queue JUnit test. Just to make sure my understanding is right, does this mean for instance, the size of the bounded queue should be zero if we approach the boundary by remove() and should be the capacity of the bounded queue if we approach the boundary by insert()?

Comment: {queue.size = 0, remove()} -> exception (underrun); {queue.size = 1 & remove()} -> queue.size == 1; {queue.size = queue.capacity-1, insert()} -> queue.size == queue.capacity; {queue.size = queue.capacity, insert()} -> exception (overflow)